# Format Dates in a Dropdownlistfor using the DisplayFormat Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I want to use the DisplayFormat Attribute of the below property so that when my dropdownlistfor is populated it uses that format. Can anyone tell me if that's possible?

The Property in my Class

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Settlement Year")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM-yyyy}")]
public DateTime SettlementYear { get; set; }
```

The Razor Code for the DropDownlistFor

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SettlementMonthID, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-4"})
    <div class="col-md-7 input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SettlementMonthID, new SelectList(Model.SettlementMonths, "Id", "SettlementYear"), "- Select A Settlement Month -", new { @class = "form-control  dropdown" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SettlementMonthID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No that's not possible. You need to generate a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` where you set the `Text` property of `SelectListItem` to the formatted string

Comment: Thanks @Stephen I was afraid of that. I think I can work with that solution though.

Comment: So I just added a DisplaySettlementYear property to my model and set that with the format I wanted when I load it the model for the first time. Then I bound the DropdownListFor to the ID and the DisplaySettlementYear property.

Answer (score 0):

So I just added a DisplaySettlementYear property to my model and set that with the format I wanted when I load it the model for the first time. Then I bound the DropdownListFor to the ID and the new DisplaySettlementYear property